# error in Eclipse while renaming a file

Tags: eclipse

While i'm trying to rename a GSP file in Eclipse `Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)` i can't rename it and this error occurs , i tried to restart the Eclipse but same issue found

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at rg.grails.ide.eclipse.refactoring.rename.action.GrailsActionOrViewRenameParticipant.getActions(GrailsActionOrViewRenameParticipant.java:175)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.refactoring.rename.action.GSPRenameParticipant.renameAction(GSPRenameParticipant.java:109)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.refactoring.rename.action.GSPRenameParticipant.checkConditions(GSPRenameParticipant.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:257)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CheckConditionsOperation.run(CheckConditionsOperation.java:85)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:121)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:209)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

any solutions to fix this ?

Comment: First yhing to consider is using recent versions of Eclipse IDE and Grails plugin.

Comment: @Mickael , i think it doesn't matter as this feature was working perfectly, i'm using this version for more than 1 year without any errors !!

Comment: Developers fix bugs between versions, there are big chances that such bug got detected and fixed in the last 2 years.

Comment: @Mickael, so you are recommending to use the latest Eclipse version and Grails plugin for it ?